# Is there a way to eliminate duplicate data without using 'distinct' or 'unique' clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-fusion-apps

I cannot use Distinct or Unique clause due to Organisation restrictions. Is there a way to modify the code so that no duplicate values are shown?
My code is listed below:

```
`SELECT PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.TITLE,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FIRST_NAME,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.LAST_NAME,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FULL_NAME,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.DISPLAY_NAME,
FROM PER_PERSON_NAMES_F,PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F, PER_PERSONS
WHERE PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.PERSON_ID=PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_ID
AND PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.PERSON_ID=PER_PERSONS.PERSON_ID
AND PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_ID=PER_PERSONS.PERSON_ID
AND name_type='GLOBAL'
ORDER BY PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FULL_NAME.`
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is probably the best method. Use the `PARTITION BY` subclause to define your unique key, and the `ORDER BY` subclause to choose the winning row based on non-key attributes when there is a duplication. Then in a parent query filter on the result of this function and select the value 1.

Comment: @PaulW If the duplicates are coming from one-to-many joins between `per_person_names_f` and either `per_all_people_f` or `per_persons` then the best method may be not to generate those duplicates in the first place and use `EXISTS` to check that `name_type='GLOBAL'` rather than joining.

Comment: The only reason why a shop would ban `distinct` is because it is overused by green developers who hide bad joins by masking the cross product they create. There is nothing wrong with `distinct` when *properly* used. But it is better to be explicit about the granularity (uniqueness) of a query block, so `group by` or `row_number()` that explicitly defines how to collapse rows is superior from a standpoint of self-documenting and avoiding easy mistakes. It forces you to really think about why you need uniqueness and how it should be defined.

Comment: @MT0 yes of course, that is most obviously the first question to ask. But once it has been determined that the joins are correct and the duplicates are natural to the data model one has to work with, there is frequently need to collapse a result set, and if one's org says "do not use distinct" then it's a legit question how to handle it in a way acceptable to such an org.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT n.TITLE,
       n.FIRST_NAME,
       n.LAST_NAME,
       n.FULL_NAME,
       n.DISPLAY_NAME
FROM   PER_PERSON_NAMES_F n
       INNER JOIN PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ap
       ON n.PERSON_ID=ap.PERSON_ID
       INNER JOIN PER_PERSONS p
       ON  n.PERSON_ID=p.PERSON_ID
       AND ap.PERSON_ID=p.PERSON_ID
WHERE  name_type='GLOBAL'
GROUP BY
       n.TITLE,
       n.FIRST_NAME,
       n.LAST_NAME,
       n.FULL_NAME,
       n.DISPLAY_NAME
ORDER BY n.FULL_NAME
```

Or, since `PERSON_ID` appears to be the primary key for a person:

```sql
SELECT MAX(n.TITLE) as title,
       MAX(n.FIRST_NAME) as first_name,
       MAX(n.LAST_NAME) as last_name,
       MAX(n.FULL_NAME) as full_name,
       MAX(n.DISPLAY_NAME) as display_name
FROM   PER_PERSON_NAMES_F n
       INNER JOIN PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ap
       ON n.PERSON_ID=ap.PERSON_ID
       INNER JOIN PER_PERSONS p
       ON  n.PERSON_ID=p.PERSON_ID
       AND ap.PERSON_ID=p.PERSON_ID
WHERE  name_type='GLOBAL'
GROUP BY
       n.PERSON_ID
ORDER BY n.FULL_NAME
```

Or use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT n.TITLE,
       n.FIRST_NAME,
       n.LAST_NAME,
       n.FULL_NAME,
       n.DISPLAY_NAME
FROM   (
  SELECT n.TITLE,
         n.FIRST_NAME,
         n.LAST_NAME,
         n.FULL_NAME,
         n.DISPLAY_NAME,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.person_id) AS rn
  FROM   PER_PERSON_NAMES_F n
         INNER JOIN PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ap
         ON n.PERSON_ID=ap.PERSON_ID
         INNER JOIN PER_PERSONS p
         ON  n.PERSON_ID=p.PERSON_ID
         AND ap.PERSON_ID=p.PERSON_ID
  WHERE  name_type='GLOBAL'
) n
WHERE    n.rn = 1
ORDER BY n.FULL_NAME
```

Alternatively, since the duplicates are probably coming from a one-to-many join then don't `JOIN` the tables use `EXISTS` instead:

```sql
SELECT n.TITLE,
       n.FIRST_NAME,
       n.LAST_NAME,
       n.FULL_NAME,
       n.DISPLAY_NAME
FROM   PER_PERSON_NAMES_F n
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F ap
                INNER JOIN PER_PERSONS p
                ON  ap.PERSON_ID=p.PERSON_ID
         WHERE  n.PERSON_ID=ap.PERSON_ID
         AND    p.name_type='GLOBAL'
       )
ORDER BY n.FULL_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

What does

> due to Organisation restrictions

mean?

---

One option is to put all columns returned by select statement into `group by` clause:

```
  SELECT per_person_names_f.title,
         per_person_names_f.first_name,
         per_person_names_f.last_name,
         per_person_names_f.full_name,
         per_person_names_f.display_name
    FROM per_person_names_f, per_all_people_f, per_persons
   WHERE     per_person_names_f.person_id = per_all_people_f.person_id
         AND per_person_names_f.person_id = per_persons.person_id
         AND per_all_people_f.person_id = per_persons.person_id
         AND name_type = 'GLOBAL'
GROUP BY per_person_names_f.title,
         per_person_names_f.first_name,
         per_person_names_f.last_name,
         per_person_names_f.full_name,
         per_person_names_f.display_name
ORDER BY per_person_names_f.full_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `MINUS` to force distinctness.

```
SELECT 
SELECT PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.TITLE,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FIRST_NAME,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.LAST_NAME,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FULL_NAME,
               PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.DISPLAY_NAME,
FROM PER_PERSON_NAMES_F,PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F, PER_PERSONS
WHERE PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.PERSON_ID=PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_ID
AND PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.PERSON_ID=PER_PERSONS.PERSON_ID
AND PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_ID=PER_PERSONS.PERSON_ID
AND name_type='GLOBAL'
UNION SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0
ORDER BY PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FULL_NAME
```

This solution is stupid, which is perhaps an advantage here. It tells future developers that you knowingly did something obviously stupid, and it will make them wonder why you did it. Because you can't add a comment to your code that says `-- I was forced to do this because my organization is run by morons.`

Comment: haha thank you so much for the help. Apparently, they asked me to use joins for every condition to remove redundancy instead of making it easy

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.TITLE,
   PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FIRST_NAME,
   PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.LAST_NAME,
   PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FULL_NAME,
   PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.DISPLAY_NAME
  FROM PER_PERSON_NAMES_F,PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F, PER_PERSONS
  WHERE PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.PERSON_ID=PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_ID
AND PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.PERSON_ID=PER_PERSONS.PERSON_ID
AND PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F.PERSON_ID=PER_PERSONS.PERSON_ID
AND name_type='GLOBAL'
GROUP BY PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.TITLE,
     PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FIRST_NAME,
     PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.LAST_NAME,
     PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FULL_NAME,
     PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.DISPLAY_NAME
ORDER BY PER_PERSON_NAMES_F.FULL_NAME;
```

Used Group by clause in the above query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).